# How to convert IQueryable complex type to generic list in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

```
 IQueryable<SystemGroup> systemGroupQuery;

 systemGroupQuery = dbContext.SystemGroups.Select(x => new SystemGroup()
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        SmsAccountId = x.SmsAccountId,
                        SmsAccount = dbContext.SmsAccounts.Where(g => g.Id 
 == x.SmsAccountId).SingleOrDefault()
                    });

 var systemGroups = systemGroupQuery.ToList();
```

While converting to list i am getting the error "The entity or complex type 'Models.Context.SystemGroup' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ToList()` before `.Select`
or
use anonymous object and map it after `.ToList()`

Linq to entities doesnt allow constructing complex typed objects in the fly

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since it is a IQueryable, I cant use ToList() before .Select. It is throwing cast error.

Comment: paste the error please, `ToList<T>()` is available for `IQueryable<T>`

also, whats the type of `dbContext.SystemGroups`?